# How to change URLs in drupal 8 page manager when using exposed filters

Tags: drupal-8

I am using panels and page manager for my pages my page is coming like http://example.com/news?country[33]=33&country[34]=34&year[116]=116&year[117]=117

I need to modify this to http://example.com/news/country-america-japan-year-2019-2020